# Puppeteer site navigation won't work if using puppetter.connect()

Tags: puppeteer

I have a puppetter script that navigates a company webapp. Everything works fine when I browse using puppetter.launch but when I use connect it arrives at a point in the navigation where the page does not appear to render, some events like onLoad don't happen. I believe they may be using anti-**scraping** techniques.

I'm listening to the events

`page.on ("load") page.on ("requestfinished") page.on ("frameattached")`

none of these occur when browsing via puppeteer.connect to connect to a running puppetter docker image.

I'm using browserless docker image.

Comment: Could be anything... Bad behaving website, anti bot detection, maybe your code is not working. You need to provide some more details.

Comment: After updating the puppeteer version everything started working